# Plot multiple plots from dataframes stored in list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2, lapply

I am trying to plot multiple plots from each data stored in the list.My code works when I am trying to plot for a single dataframe in a list:

```
ggplot(data.frame(s[1]), aes(x = No, y = Val))  +
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed",color="red")+geom_point()
```

but unable to work it when I am running a loop.

```
for (i in 1:3)
{
  ggplot(data.frame(s[i]), aes(x = No, y = Val))  +
    geom_line(linetype = "dashed",color="red")+geom_point()
  i = i+1
}
```

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Could you expand on how it doesn't work? Do the plots not show? Do the data look wrong? Would you like to save the plots in a list? Do you get errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the plot within the for loop on a variable and print as follows:

```
for (i in 1:3)
{
  myplot <- ggplot(data.frame(s[i]), aes(x = No, y = Val))  +
    geom_line(linetype = "dashed",color="red")+geom_point()
  print(myplot)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also store all plots in a list

```
myplot <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
   myplot[i] <- ggplot(data.frame(s[i]), aes(x = No, y = Val)) +
   geom_line(linetype = "dashed", color = "red") + 
   geom_point()
}
```